# Vectorize the code to get the Time when max of HIGH occurs in a data.table [R lang]

Tags: r, data.table, vectorization

I've a data.table (using the R package) with the following structure, given below the `dput` of a sample of the original data.table:

```
structure(list(DATE = c(20141028L, 20141028L, 20141028L, 20141028L, 
20141028L, 20141028L, 20141028L, 20141028L, 20141028L, 20141028L, 
20141030L, 20141030L, 20141030L, 20141030L, 20141030L, 20141030L, 
20141030L, 20141030L, 20141030L, 20141030L), TIME = c(917L, 918L, 
920L, 921L, 923L, 924L, 925L, 929L, 930L, 931L, 935L, 936L, 937L, 
940L, 942L, 943L, 944L, 945L, 947L, 949L), CLOSE = c(129.5, 129.5, 
129.1, 129.65, 129.75, 129.75, 129.65, 129.5, 129.75, 129.45, 
989.7, 995, 998, 995.55, 981, 983.45, 981.25, 983.2, 981.5, 981.5
), HIGH = c(129.5, 129.5, 129.5, 129.65, 129.75, 129.75, 129.65, 
129.5, 129.75, 129.45, 989.7, 995, 1000, 995.6, 981, 983.45, 
981.25, 983.2, 981.5, 981.5), LOW = c(129.5, 129.5, 129.1, 129.65, 
129.65, 129.75, 129.65, 129.5, 129.35, 129.45, 989.7, 995, 998, 
995.55, 981, 983.45, 981.25, 983.2, 981.5, 981.5), OPEN = c(129.5, 
129.5, 129.5, 129.65, 129.65, 129.75, 129.65, 129.5, 129.65, 
129.45, 989.7, 995, 1000, 995.6, 981, 983.45, 981.25, 983.2, 
981.5, 981.5), VOLUME = c(99L, 10L, 501L, 20L, 160L, 358L, 50L, 
88L, 171L, 25L, 117L, 136L, 249L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 12L, 2L, 11L, 10L
), SYMBOL = c("QQQQ", "QQQQ", "QQQQ", "QQQQ", 
"QQQQ", "QQQQ", "QQQQ", "QQQQ", "QQQQ", 
"QQQQ", "GS", "GS", "GS", "GS", 
"GS", "GS", "GS", "GS", "GS", "GS"
)), .Names = c("DATE", "TIME", "CLOSE", "HIGH", "LOW", "OPEN", 
"VOLUME", "SYMBOL"), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x00000000003c0788>)
```

I need to find the time, in each day for each ticker, when that day's maximum HIGH occurs.

For e.g. on the date `20141020`, for symbol `QQQQ` the maximum HIGH occurs at time `1017`. I'm putting the times in a matrix. Below is the code I've used to brute force this, but with multiple loops it's getting excruciatingly slow. `length(ticklist)` is 1481, `length(dites)` is 20.

```
highmat = matrix(nrow = length(ticklist),ncol = length(dites))
colnames(highmat) = dites
rownames(highmat) = ticklist

for(k in 2:length(ticklist)){
  for(m in 1:length(dites)){
    fluff = nall.tab[(DATE == dites[m])&(SYMBOL == ticklist[k])]
    if(dim(fluff)[1] > 0){
      maxloc = which.max(fluff$HIGH)
      highmat[k,m] = fluff$TIME[maxloc]
    }
    else{
      highmat[k,m] = NA
    }
  }
}
```

Please let me know if there are any faster option, probably by vectorizing, which has stumped me in this case.

Edit: Replaced the `str` output with `dput` output, hope that helps.

Comment: Does `dt[,list(maxtime=TIME[which.max(HIGH)]),by=list(SYMBOL,DATE)]` work for you?

Comment: Great, it works perfectly, and is several order magnitude faster than my naive code. Thanks nicola.